# Quotation Form - Echo two values from a PHP form selection

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to create a quotation form. This will be email to myself and the person who has filled in the form. I want to echo the selected value (I currently have this working) & assign a integer value to the selection. I then want to add the integers up to give a total. In my example below I have just included one selection but I will have quite a few of them in the form. Any help would be great!

```
<label>What time would you like to start?
    <select required name="drop_off_time" id="drop_off_time-select" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['drop_off_time']))  echo $_POST['drop_off_time'];?>">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="8:00am">8:00am</option>
        <option value="8:30am">8:30am</option>
        <option value="9:00am">9:00am</option>
    </select>
</label>


if(isset($_REQUEST['drop_off_time']) && $_REQUEST['drop_off_time'] == '0') { 
echo 'Please select a time.'; 
} 
$drop_off_time = $_POST['drop_off_time'];


$emailTo = 'me@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Fees Form Submission from '.$name;
$sendCopy = trim($_POST['sendCopy']);
$body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nComments: $comments \n\nDrop Off Time: $drop_off_time \n\nTotal: £$total";
$headers = 'From: My Site <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

This all works fine. My problem is that I want to assign an integer to the selection. I've done this using a switch but it keeps printing out the selected value not the new value I have assigned. The code for this is below.

```
$drop_off_time_price = 0;
switch ($drop_off_time_price) {
case 0;
    echo 0;
    break;
case "8:00am":
  echo 100;
  break;
case "8:30am":
  echo 10000;
  break;
case "9:00am":
  echo 100000;
  break; 
}

//Getting the total
$total = $drop_off_time_price;
```

This is what the email looks like

Name: Frank

Email: me@mail.com

Comments: I get the selected value but no the total....

Drop Off Time: 8:00am

Total: £0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems in your logic:

1. You should be checking against **$drop_off_time** in your switch statements. So it should be:

   ```
   switch ($drop_off_time) {
   ```
2. as @FloatingRock has mentioned, case 0; should be:

   ```
   case 0:
   ```
3. instead of echo 0 you should assign that value to `$drop_off_time_price`

   ```
   $drop_off_time_price = 0;
   ```

So your full example should be something like:

```
    $drop_off_time_price = 0;
    switch ($drop_off_time) {
        case "8:00am":
           $drop_off_time_price = 100;
           break;
        case "8:30am":
           $drop_off_time_price = 10000;
           break;
        case "9:00am":
           $drop_off_time_price = 100000;
           break; 
    }
```

**Note:** You can also remove the check for 0 as in my example since you are already setting the default value for 0 to be `0` price.

Comment: Thanks @Kypros! I changed my switch to check against $drop_off_time and its working perfectly. I really appreciate your clear answer

Comment: Nice catch there @StuartNelson . It's good because it means you are really got the issue. Please accept the answer if it fixed your problem. :)

Comment: I really have now. It makes total sense why it wasn't working! If only more people would give answers like yours. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

In your `switch` statement, you're using `case 0;` when it should be `case 0:` with a `:`

Comment: thanks for pointing this out! Still just getting a 0 for my total. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd block of code, which you are using apparently to assign an integer, does not seem to be what you want. I suppose, you are using this block to calculate $total, which is then being used in your email body $body. The switch block however, does not calculate or assign anything to any variable. It just prints out some values - which is 0 in your example.

My suggestion: please post all of the code and you will probably get a detailed answer.